# Main form controls not refreshing when running BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

My code looks like this:

```
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            fastDataListView1.ClearObjects();
            fastDataListView1.DataSource = null;
            fastDataListView1.RebuildColumns();
            fastDataListView1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
            fastDataListView1.Refresh();
            fastDataListView1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Text = "Working...";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            fastDataListView1.Refresh();

            try
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            finally
            {

                fastDataListView1.BackColor = Color.White;
                fastDataListView1.Enabled = true;

                button1.Text = "Refresh Data...";
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
```

The background worker runs fine and gets the data that is should. My issue is that the controls on the main form don't seem to change when I change properties like:

```
            button1.Text = "Working...";
```

before starting background worker. I CAN drag the main form around and it is responsive as it should. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What sort of app is this? UWP? WPF? Winforms?

Comment: `My issue is that the controls on the main form don't seem to change` because you are probably doing it on the UI thread and **you should never do that**, you should be doing it in the report progress event... How about you post your `DoWork` method...

Comment: You assign button1.Text again about a microsecond later, so you can't see "Working".   The Enabled property doesn't work for the same reason.  Just keep in mind that *starting* a background worker takes very little time and it doesn't complete until it raises the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: @Hans Passant  - That's it. Thank you.

Comment: @DevNoob  - Winforms